# Where does the Azure Machine ACI Webservice deploy?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

When we deploy a model as an ACIWebService in Azure Machine Learning Service, we do not need to specify any `deployment_target`.

According to the [AzureML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#deploy-workspace--name--models--inference-config-none--deployment-config-none--deployment-target-none--overwrite-false-) for `azureml.core.model.model` class,

```
deployment_target
ComputeTarget
default value: None
A ComputeTarget to deploy the Webservice to. As Azure Container Instances has no associated ComputeTarget, leave this parameter as None to deploy to Azure Container Instances.
```

What does Microsoft mean by

> As Azure Container Instances has no associated ComputeTarget

In which "Compute Target" is an ACIWebService deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview) itself is the compute platform. It spins up a container in a serverless-fashion.